# Append value in df rows

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I have a column in dataframe (df) for which I want to append value (not constant, instead variable). An example will make it more clear:

```
> df
     geneID Sample.290
1         1  0.4018499
2        10  0.2694255
3       100  1.4441846
4      1000 13.7652753
5     10000  2.1552100
6 100008586  0.2358481
```

I want to append character "ENSG" and multiple "000" so that total length of the each value will be 15 (including ENSG). For example the output should be:

```
         geneID           Sample.290
1        ENSG00000000001  0.4018499
2        ENSG00000000010  0.2694255
3        ENSG00000000100  1.4441846
4        ENSG00000001000 13.7652753
5        ENSG00000010000  2.1552100
6        ENSG00100008586  0.2358481
```

Comment: See, also, `?sprintf`; `sprintf("ENSG%011d", df$geneID)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `str_pad` from `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
df$geneID <- paste0('ENSG', str_pad(df$geneID, width = 11, pad = '0'))
df
#           geneID Sample.290
#1 ENSG00000000001  0.4018499
#2 ENSG00000000010  0.2694255
#3 ENSG00000000100  1.4441846
#4 ENSG00000001000 13.7652753
#5 ENSG00000010000  2.1552100
#6 ENSG00100008586  0.2358481
```

Answer (score 3):

Using basic function:

```
df$geneID <- sapply(df$geneID,function(x) paste("ENSG",
                    paste(rep(0,(15-nchar(x)-nchar("ENSG"))),collapse = ""),x,sep=""))
```

"15" total length of variable;

Answer (score 2):

The `stri_pad_left` function in the `stringi` package will do what you want:

```
df$geneID <- paste0('ENSG', stringi::stri_pad_left(df[, 'geneID'], width = 11, pad = '0'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do (using base R functions):

```
# df
     # geneID Sample.290
# 1         1  0.4018499
# 2        10  0.2694255
# 3       100  1.4441846
# 4      1000 13.7652753
# 5     10000  2.1552100
# 6 100008586  0.2358481

a="ENSG00000000000"
df[,'geneID']=sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) 
paste0(substring(a, 1, 15-nchar(df[i,'geneID'])), df[i,'geneID']))

# > df
           # geneID Sample.290
# 1 ENSG00000000001  0.4018499
# 2 ENSG00000000010  0.2694255
# 3 ENSG00000000100  1.4441846
# 4 ENSG00000001000 13.7652753
# 5 ENSG00000010000  2.1552100
# 6 ENSG00100008586  0.2358481
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Sotos example (it was what I immediately thought when reading your post), str_pad command